# Checking alternating tensors on $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, tensors, bilinear-form

I'm trying to solve the following question : 
Which of the following are alternating tensors in $\mathbb R^4$ and express those that are in terms of the elementary tensors on $\mathbb  R^4$:

\begin{align*}
g(x, y) &= x_1y_3 - x_3y_2 \\\
h(x, y) &= x_1^3y_2^3 - x_2^3y_1^3
\end{align*}

a similar question has been asked before, but I didn't really understand the answer, here is the link to the other question : 
[Which of these maps are alternating tensors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121920/which-of-these-maps-are-alternating-tensors?rq=1)

Attempt at a solution :

The function h is not a tensor since its not linear in $ x,y $, $ c*h(x,y) \not= h(cx,y)$ and similarly for y 
For g i'm not really sure, if create a 3x3 matrix to calculate the derivative for g, one of the row will be completely zero, and hence, $g(y,x) \not= -g(x,y)$
This is what I think I'm not exactly sure, is there a standard way to approach questions like these, in particular if h was linear in each of its variables how would you approach that and similarly say how would you attempt this question for lets say 
$g(x,y) =  x_1y_3 - x_3y_2 + x_2y_1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least $g(x,y)=-g(y,x)$ which when you test it is not satisfied. This also holds for your alternate expression. You can anti-symmetrize any tensor as
$$
\frac12(g(x,y)-g(y,x)).
$$

Comment: So this expression would need to equal g(x,y) for the function to be an alternating tensor ? Also are my answers to the above question correct ?

Comment: For $h$ it is correct, for $g$ not, as $x_1y_2-x_2y_1$ is anti-symmetric but still has the third (and fourth) row of the corresponding matrix zero. Just compare $g(x,y)$ and $-g(y,x)=x_2y_3-x_3y_1$ to find the contradiction.

Comment: Just to be clear: $g(x,y) = x_1y_3 - x_3y_2 \text and -g(y,x) = x_2y_3 - x_3y_1$ hence, they are not alternating tensors since $g(x,y) \not= -g(y,x)$